# How can I get a selected child product of a specific option of a bundle quote item?

Tags: orders, magento2.2, bundled-product, quoteitem

I have `$quoteItem` (`Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteItem`) which represents a bundle product.

The order options are fetched via

```
$typeInstance = $quoteItem->getProduct()->getTypeInstance();
$this->orderOptions = $typeInstance->getOrderOptions($quoteItem->getProduct());
```

But in the returned array, there seems to be no link to the Product Entity IDs of the selections?

It is possible to fetch the *available* selections for an option:

```
    $selections = $typeInstance->getSelectionsCollection([self::MY_OPTION_ID], $quoteItem->getProduct());
```

But can I get the *chosen* option out of this?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    $selections = $typeInstance->getSelectionsCollection([self::MY_OPTION_ID], $quoteItem->getProduct());
    $selected = $this->orderOptions['info_buyRequest']['bundle_option'][self::MY_OPTION_ID];
    $product = $selections->getItemById($selected);
```